# R package that implements maxent for NLP tasks

Tags: r, nlp, maxent

I am searching for an R package that implements MaxEnt for NLP tasks (i.e. for situations with large no. of parameters).

The requirement is to perform Named Entity Recognition on medical text. I got used to relying on CRF++ for sequence labelling jobs but for this particular entity recognition task at hand, I dont want the transition/label input.

I have checked Maxent Package - it creates a tf-idf representation which I dont want. I need to provide my features as combinations of previous and next words, pos tags, etc. Very similar to how one would use CRF++.

Comment: This question is an extension of this discussion: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17436/logistic-regression-with-lbfgs-solver that did not seem to have an answer for an R implementation.

Comment: There is no decent R-native solution for named entity recognition. You can use `spacyr` which is an R wrapper for spaCy (in Python). It's not on cran but it works mostly fine on most platforms (so I believe as a developer of the package). https://github.com/kbenoit/spacyr

Comment: Thanks. I will try out spaCy and see how it goes.